# When you share apps in android, do you share data as well?

Tags: android

Is it true when you share apps with others that the data sent is the default data? For example if I created an app and I upload some photos on that app. If I use the APK extractor and send it to the receiver, will they see the photos I uploaded on the app or will they see no photos at all by default?

Is there a way to share data whilst sharing the app?

Below is where I have the idea of sharing apps:
https://www.wikihow.tech/Extract-APK-File-of-Any-App-on-Your-Android-Phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the data is shared by default because there are three ways of storing data permanently, shared preferences, SQLite databases, and back-end servers

when you transport the apk the shared preferences won't get transported with the apk since they are stored internally on the device in the app's folder. SQLite databases are the same thing.

now if you want to be able to share the photos then you should use a backend, the app will connect to that backend and get all the data from it, I recommend back4app.com it's a free parse server hosting platform.

and if you want more control over the server use AWS but be aware that using parse server on AWS ec2 (winch is the fastest way to launch the server) is bad because it has a lot of fewer features then back4app plus you have to connect using an ssh client and if you exceed your free tier usage you will be charged